# MySQL - Why is my innodb_force_recovery being shown as "unknown variable"

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

Okay firstly, i ran

`locate my.cnf`

Which gave

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

This is also the default config location set by mysqld

and then on editing the file `my.cnf` adding under [mysql]

```
[mysql]
innodb_force_recovery = 3
```

and then rebooting mysqld and trying to logon `mysql -u root -p`

i get an error saying

```
mysql: unknown variable 'innodb_force_recovery=3'
```

Also on running `show variables`

i see this field

`innodb_force_recovery = 0`

I'm using Mysql `5.5.44`

is there a particular reason this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[mysql] section is used by mysql client.

Set your option in [mysqld] section.