# Trying to repair a corrupted InnoDB table on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have a corrupted MariaDB database. The corruption was due to a power outage.

I can't boot the MariaDB without putting `innodb_force_recovery`. I've set it up to 3.

It's InnoDB so I can't repair it. It should do it on your own.

When I try to dump the table, I got the following error:

```
mysqldump: Error 1034: Index for table 'statistics' is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table `statistics` at row: 36157
```

At this point I'm hitting the wall because I can't figure out how to fix the index.

Tried to run as recommended by Georg `mariadb-check` command and I got the following error:

```
2022-06-03 15:08:15 4 [ERROR] InnoDB: Space id and page no stored in the page, read in are [page id: space=201, page number=30781], should be [page id: space=201, page number=32829]
2022-06-03 15:08:15 4 [ERROR] InnoDB: Space id and page no stored in the page, read in are [page id: space=201, page number=30721], should be [page id: space=201, page number=32769]
2022-06-03 15:08:15 4 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Trying to read page number 2188681215 in space 201, space name homeassistant/states, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384
220603 15:08:15 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
Server version: 10.4.19-MariaDB-1:10.4.19+maria~focal
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=66
thread_count=2
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68686 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
Thread pointer: 0x7f3c000c48
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7f843028b8 thread_stack 0x30000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x30)[0x55886ff4c0]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x49c)[0x55882085b4]
linux-vdso.so.1(__kernel_rt_sigreturn+0x0)[0x7f87a4378c]
/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xe0)[0x7f870fa138]
/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x110)[0x7f870e6d68]
mysqld(+0xb241a0)[0x55884d41a0]
mysqld(+0x5a1724)[0x5587f51724]
mysqld(+0xbc3728)[0x5588573728]
mysqld(+0xb81184)[0x5588531184]
mysqld(+0xb5e44c)[0x558850e44c]
mysqld(+0xb39644)[0x55884e9644]
mysqld(+0x59d0d8)[0x5587f4d0d8]
mysqld(+0xb9fa84)[0x558854fa84]
mysqld(+0xba0008)[0x5588550008]
mysqld(+0xb913e8)[0x55885413e8]
mysqld(+0x9ffcb4)[0x55883afcb4]
mysqld(_ZN7handler7ha_openEP5TABLEPKcijP11st_mem_rootP4ListI6StringE+0x58)[0x558820e0b8]
mysqld(_Z21open_table_from_shareP3THDP11TABLE_SHAREPK25st_mysql_const_lex_stringjjjP5TABLEbP4ListI6StringE+0x628)[0x55880d5f30]
mysqld(_Z10open_tableP3THDP10TABLE_LISTP18Open_table_context+0x6dc)[0x5587fcb1f4]
mysqld(_Z11open_tablesP3THDRK14DDL_options_stPP10TABLE_LISTPjjP19Prelocking_strategy+0x9f8)[0x5587fce378]
mysqld(_Z20open_and_lock_tablesP3THDRK14DDL_options_stP10TABLE_LISTbjP19Prelocking_strategy+0x38)[0x5587fceb30]
mysqld(+0x758608)[0x5588108608]
mysqld(+0x7595dc)[0x55881095dc]
mysqld(_ZN19Sql_cmd_check_table7executeEP3THD+0x8c)[0x558810b24c]
mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0xd80)[0x5588024370]
mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_statebb+0x1f8)[0x558802a200]
mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcjbb+0xfb0)[0x558802c008]
mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0xfc)[0x558802de34]
mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP7CONNECT+0x290)[0x55880feaf8]
mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x44)[0x55880fec1c]
/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x84fc)[0x7f874e24fc]
/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xd467c)[0x7f8719767c]
Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0x7f3c0118f0): CHECK TABLE `events`
Connection ID (thread ID): 4
Status: NOT_KILLED
Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=on,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on,condition_pushdown_for_subquery=on,rowid_filter=on,condition_pushdown_from_having=on
The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file...
Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Resource Limits:
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             unlimited            unlimited            processes
Max open files            1048576              1048576              files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       29948                29948                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
Core pattern: |/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h
```

Comment: At what value of innodb_force_recovery can you start the MariaDB ? Can you start it with innodb_force_recovery =1, if so you can try with repair table statistics

Comment: Please ask database admin related questions on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO, not here on the programming focused SO.

Comment: At `innodb_force_recovery=1`, MariaDB does not boot up.

Comment: The minimum it starts is `2` btw.

Comment: @Mazzy have a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/851342/mysql-crashed-and-not-starting-even-after-adding-innodb-force-recovery)

Comment: @ErgestBasha thank you but it's a dead end. it does not bring me anywhere. I do not have backups.

Comment: @Mazzy Could you post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE statistics; ?   The mysqldump clearly has identified row 36157 IS the problem.

Comment: This URL may be of value to you - in this case it was an error 1034 caused by an out of space condition.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162969/ample-disk-space-with-error-1034-incorrect-key-file-for-table-table-name-tr

Comment: In 12 hours, if you are still hassled with this problem, view profile and get in touch, please.

Comment: @Mazzy We are 72 hours later, my invitation is still open.  Thanks

Comment: I haven't solved it yet. sorry did not have much time this week. going to try to solve during the weekend and I will post my results

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a backup
2. Check which tables might have corrupted indexes:
   `mariadb-check -c database`
3. Force a rebuild with
   `OPTIMIZE TABLE corrupted_table`

Comment: unfortunately this process is not applicable to me.

at least I've tried to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE corrupted_table` and the MariaDB completely crashes.

Comment: Which server version do you use? Is there any information/backtrace after crash in error log?

Comment: 10.4.19. let me collect those information

Comment: Can't even get to run the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` cmd. Once I run `mariadb-check`  I get immediately the error reported above and the process fails.

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to read page number 2188681215 in space 201, space name homeassistant/states, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384

Here one of pages in the primary index of the `homeassistant/states` table stored incorrect values, so InnoDB crashes when it accesses the page.

If InnoDB starts with any `innodb_force_recovery` > 0 but crashes during a mysqldump operation you can try to skip corrupted pages:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Adjust your values here
host=localhost
user=root
db=test
table=test
PK=id
newtable=newtest2
# end of user defined values

read -p "Password: " -s password
echo ""
if [ "xxx$password" = "xxx" ]
then
        pass_cmd=""
else
        pass_cmd="-p$password"
fi
mysql -h $host -u $user $pass_cmd -e "show databases" $db
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "Credentials are ok!"
else
        echo "Can't run query SHOW DATABASES"
        echo "Check what's wrong"
        exit
fi
minPK=`mysql -sN -h $host -u $user $pass_cmd -e "SELECT MIN($PK) FROM $table" $db`
maxPK=`mysql -sN -h $host -u $user $pass_cmd -e "SELECT MAX($PK) FROM $table" $db`
a=$minPK
b=$maxPK
let chunk=$b-$a

function insert_range {
q="INSERT IGNORE INTO \`$newtable\` SELECT * FROM \`$table\` WHERE \`$PK\` >= $1 and \`$PK\` <= $2"
mysql -h $host -u $user $pass_cmd -e "$q" $db 2>/dev/null
}
successful_tries=0
echo "Primary key ($PK) range: $minPK .. $maxPK"
while true
do
        insert_range $a $b
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo "Good, primary key range: $a .. $b"
                let a=$b+1
                let b=$b+$chunk
                let successful_tries=$successful_tries+1
        else
                echo "Bad luck, primary key range: $a .. $b"
                let chunk=$chunk/2
                let b=$a+$chunk
                mysqladmin -h $host -u $user $pass_cmd ping > /dev/null 2>&1
                while [ $? -ne 0 ]
                do
                        mysqladmin -h $host -u $user $pass_cmd ping > /dev/null 2>&1
                done
                successful_tries=0
        fi
        if [ $a -gt $maxPK ]
        then
                exit
        fi
        if [ $chunk -eq 0 ]
        then
                let a=$a+1
                let b=$a+1
                let chunk=1
        fi
        # If things are going well, increase pace
        if [ $successful_tries -gt 5 ]
        then
                let chunk=$chunk*2
        fi
done
```

P.S.

I wonder if it's really the primary index. If it's actually the secondary index you can drop it, reload the table and then create the secondary indexes again.

[1] https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb/blob/develop/fetch_data.sh

Comment: I've run it and I got several messages like

./fetch_data.sh: line 61: [: 2434: unary operator expected
Bad luck, primary key range: 2435 .. 2436
./fetch_data.sh: line 61: [: 2435: unary operator expected
Bad luck, primary key range: 2436 .. 2437
./fetch_data.sh: line 61: [: 2436: unary operator expected

Comment: btw I've fixed the bash issue so to not get unary operator error and I get now the only error


`ERROR 1030 (HY000) at line 1: Got error 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine" from storage engine InnoDB
Primary key (id) range: 1 ..
Bad luck, primary key range: 1 ..`

Comment: so to be precise and to get more insight the bash script fail here

`++ mysql -sN -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e 'SELECT MAX(id) FROM statistics' homeassistant
ERROR 1030 (HY000) at line 1: Got error 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine" from storage engine InnoDB`

Comment: so it cannot provide the `maxPK`

Comment: while mariadb returns as error: `2022-06-03 15:55:33 14 [ERROR] InnoDB: We detected index corruption in an InnoDB type table. You have to dump + drop + reimport the table or, in a case of widespread corruption, dump all InnoDB tables and recreate the whole tablespace. If the mysqld server crashes after the startup or when you dump the tables. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.`

Comment: can you hardcode maxPK if you know what it should be?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know which is the max ID

Comment: Can you guess form `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'statistics'`?

Comment: Let me try to run and see what I get

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tnLi75hk - this is what I get. so let's try to run again the script as max PK 291074

Comment: https://pastebin.com/unbbA1hR - no luck get bad sector.

Comment: Rows  is 291074, so max PK value could be ~300000. It's a total speculation though - you know your data better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245309/discussion-between-akuzminsky-and-mazzy).

Answer (score 0):

Many of my errors were very similar to this situation. But for me, any `innodb_force_recovery` level would result in a recovery that occupied all CPU and it would never be able to start. Removing the `ib_logfile` [MariaDB file](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-redo-log/) wouldn't work [as did work](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/87693/163352) with others.

So, [alternatively](https://serverfault.com/a/540733/487033), it could help some situations to simply disable InnoDB, which worked in my case.

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32500670/10343144), under:

```sql
[mysqld]
```

Add this, instead of `innodb_force_recovery=`:

```sql
innodb=OFF
default_storage_engine=MyISAM
```

I was running Arch, and `grep` revealed that there was already a `[mysqld]` statement in `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf`, so I put it there.

`systemctl start mysql` worked like a charm, I entered from the CLI, and I got my work done.